# Create async method for queued timer based HTTP call

Tags: c#, async-await, queue, task

I have a class, which holds a queue of requests, which will be collected and send to an Web API via HTTP call after a time interval of max 1 second:

```cs
    public class AsyncValueTimerIntervalWriter
    {
        private class ValueRequest
        {
            public string FullName { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }
        }

        private readonly IValuesClient _valuesClient; // auto generated Swagger HTTP client

        private List<ValueRequest> _valueRequests = new List<ValueRequest>();
        private object _valuesLock = new object();

        private Timer _timer;

        public AsyncValueTimerIntervalWriter(IValuesClient valuesClient)
        {
            _valuesClient = valuesClient;
        }

        public void Start() 
        {
            _timer = new Timer(o => WriteValuesToServer(), null, 0, 1000);
        }

        public void Stop() 
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
        }

        public void AddWrite(string fullName, object value)
        {
            lock (_valuesLock)
            {
                _valueRequests.Add(new ValueRequest { FullName = fullName, Value = value });
            }
        }

        private async void WriteValuesToServer()
        {
            IList<ValueRequest> values;

            lock (_valuesLock)
            {
                values = _valueRequests.ToArray();
                _valueRequests.Clear();
            }

            if (values.Any())
            {
                await _valuesClient.SetValuesAsync(values); // Sends HTTP POST request
            }
        }
    }
```

Caller example:

```cs
var asyncWriter = new AsyncValueTimerIntervalWriter(...);
asyncWriter.AddWrite("My.Var.Tree.VarName", 1234);
asyncWriter.AddWrite("My.Var.Tree.AnotherVar", "Test");

// after max 1 sec the values are written to server
```

**My goal** is to write an async method, which also adds a value to write, and returns when the value is written:

```cs
await asyncWriter.WriteAsync("My.Var.Tree.VarName", 1234);
// should continue after written to server
```

**Important:** I need to handle requests in a queue, because the writer may be stopped at any time and it is not allowed to loose requests. After start the writer again, the added requests needs to be send to server.

I tried to use the ManualResetEvent, but it feels strange:

```cs
...
public Task WriteAsync(string fullName, object value)
{
    var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    lock (_valuesLock)
    {
        _valueRequests.Add(
            new ValueRequest 
            { 
                FullName = fullName, 
                Value = value, 
                CompletedEvent = resetEvent 
            });
    }

    resetEvent.WaitOne();

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private async void WriteValuesToServer()
{
    IList<ValueRequest> values;

    lock (_valuesLock)
    {
        values = _valueRequests.ToArray();
        _valueRequests.Clear();
    }

    if (values.Any())
    {
        await _valuesClient.SetValuesAsync(values); // Sends HTTP POST request

        foreach (var value as values)
            value.CompletedEvent?.Set();
    }
}
...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `TaskCompletionSource` within the ValueEntry class to pass a signal from the writer to the caller.

```
private class ValueEntry
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    protected readonly TaskCompletionSource _tcs = new TaskCompleteionSource();

    public Task AwaitCompletion()
    {
        return _tcs.Task;
    }

    public Task MarkComplete()
    {
        return _tcs.SetResult();
    }
}
```

Small change to WriteValuesToServer:

```
public async Task WriteValuesToServer()
{
    // snip 
    if (values.Any())
    {
        await _emsClient.SetValuesAsync(values); // Sends HTTP POST request

        foreach (var value as values)
            await value.MarkComplete();
    }
}
```

Now your writer is very simple:

```
public Task WriteAsync(string fullName, object value)
{
    var request = new ValueRequest { FullName = fullName, Value = value };

    lock (_valuesLock)
    {
        _valueRequests.Add(request)
    };
    await request.AwaitCompletion();
}
```

Also, I suggest you look into using a [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0), which is designed to handle a producer/consumer queue, and would allow you to get rid of most of your `lock` blocks.